# Why does this Perl code work from the shell, but not from a script?

Tags: perl, for-loop, foreach

I have a simple question. I have been using the zoidberg perl shell to get myself familiarized with perl interactively. I like being able to test my stuff on the fly before I flesh out a script. (I am a novice learner.)

My question is, in the shell I can do the following:

```
@a = `df -h | grep /dev/mapper | cut -c 48-`

for $i (@a) { @b=`ls $i` }
print @b;
```

However, when I put this in a script in linux:

```
#!/bin/perl
```

I see the following error when I run the script:

```
syntax error at perl_diskstats.perl line 5, near "$i ( "
Execution of perl_diskstats.perl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Am I doing something obvious here? What exactly am I doing wrong? I thought the format was..

```
foreach $var (@array) { codeblock }
```

... right?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your first line.

Comment: holy moly you are awesome, and I am so dumb thank you!

Comment: @ire_and_curses You should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your first line.

Answer (score 0):

Also you are missing `use strict`, and the `my` declarations.

```
use strict;

my @a = `df -h | grep /dev/mapper | cut -c 48-`;

my @b;
for my $i (@a) { @b=`ls $i` }

print @b;
```

Start off on the habit of `use strict` now, while you're still beginning. It will save you in the longterm.